# What is the name used for this type of connectors?

Tags: electrical-engineering, connections

I am trying to identify the following connector used in an outdoor lighting product. Dimensions are length of 30mm and diameter of approximately 8 mm. I have done several google searches without much success.

Does anyone in this forum have experience using this type of connector or similar connector? If so please share appropriate search terms. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try the search term water proof or water resistance connectors for electric bikes.

Here is similar [Electric Bike Connector](http://www.szrealeader.com/a/PRODUCTS/PRODUCTSC/45.html)

[image]

Here another similar connector used in Electric Bikes

[image]

[image]

Here is similar connector from e-bay

[image]

[image]

Looks like the supplier name is [Higo Waterproof Connectors](http://www.higocon.com/English/ProductDetail?id=2045&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIuIuW56zs6gIVuQiICR2fywrtEAAYASABEgJxpvD_BwE)

Also take a look at [Korean Cable and Components](http://www.kcc.de/). They are based in Germany.

[image]

Another connector from Aohua

2 Pin Waterproof Led Cable Connector Ip65 For Light Bar

[image]

**References:**

- [Shenzhen Aohua Electric Corporation](https://www.waterproofplug.com/about-us_d1)

Answer (score 1):

Twin port connection. Usually for voltages under 25Vdc. It also has a restrictor edge to ensure it can only connect one way... the correct circuit designed way.